# Command substitution into bash script $1 value

Tags: bash, regex, command

I have this simple script which changes permissions on my apache2 websites

```
/var/www/html# cat permissions_setup.sh 
chown -R root $1
chgrp -R www-data $1
chmod -R 750 $1
chmod g+s $1
```

I have two `.sh` shell scripts in my `html/` directory

```
/var/www/html# ll
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root     4096 Jul  5 16:45 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root     4096 Jun 13 18:37 ../
drwxr-s--- 5 root www-data 4096 Jun  6 18:17 foo.com/
drwxr-s--- 5 root www-data 4096 Jun 13 18:52 bar.org/
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Jun 13 18:13 barfoo.com/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       67 Jul  5 16:44 permissions_setup.sh*
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     4096 Jun 13 18:42 foobar.com/
-rwx------ 1 root root     1163 Jun 13 18:41 website_add.sh*
```

I have already ran the script on two websites. I am trying to use command substitution on the other sites as such:

```
/var/www/html# ./permissions_setup.sh $(ls -I "*.sh")
```

or

```
/var/www/html# ls -I "*.sh" $(./permissions_setup.sh)
chown: missing operand after ‘root’
Try 'chown --help' for more information.
chgrp: missing operand after ‘www-data’
Try 'chgrp --help' for more information.
chmod: missing operand after ‘750’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
chmod: missing operand after ‘g+s’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
```

But neither commands changed the permissions on all the websites. I am not interested in editing the script. Am I able to use command substitution in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to edit the script:

```
for f in $(ls -I "*.sh"); do ./permissions_setup.sh $f; done;
```

Comment: [There's an award for this...](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#ls)

Comment: I don't think that applies here as the `-I "*.sh"` is used to exclude files and the double quotes keep it from being expanded by the shell.